# Change Defaults of a Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I understand that you can create a plugin with public defaults like this:

```
(function($){
$.fn.hilight = function(options) {
   var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.hilight.defaults, options);
   this.css(opts);
};
$.fn.hilight.defaults = {
   foreground: 'red'
};
})(jQuery);
```

And then I can change the defaults from the outside by:

```
$.fn.hilight.defaults.foreground='blue';
```

My question(s) is how can this be done with the $.fn.extend() syntax:

```
(function($){
   $.fn.extend({
     hililght: function(options){
       var defaults={foreground: 'red',}
       var opt=$.extend(defaults,options);
      }
   });
})(jQuery)
```

And how can I change multiple defaults?

Answer (score 5):

You *could* do this:

```
(function($){
   $.fn.extend({
     hilight: function(options){
       var opt=$.extend(defaults,options);
     }
   });
   $.extend($.fn.hilight, {defaults: {
        foreground: 'red'
   }});
})(jQuery)
```

But there isn't much point. `$.fn.extend` is only useful when you have multiple properties to extend, but you only have `hilight`. Stick to your first example, it's more readable and (slightly) more efficient.

jQuery's `extend` functionality comes in handy for your second question, about changing multiple defaults. This is what `extend` was really designed for:

```
$.extend($.fn.hilight.defaults, {
    foreground: "red",
    background: "yellow",
    height: 100
    // and so on...
});
```

Comment: I would be using multiple functions inside the $.fn.extend() so it would end up being efficient. Thanks for the second bit of code.